# Updating Json Schema in vscode by other plugins

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a vs code plugin which actually validates a custom JSON formatted file with schema. However it is possible to validate the static schema, but what i am looking for is here any way to update the schema programmatically. As user can create schema file within workspace or refer to any external schema file, plugin will merge all the schema's based on certain specifications and validate the JSON files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77433#issuecomment-512726599)

- Register a TextDocumentContentProvider for a new URL schema (let's say 'fooSchema')
  in your extension, associate file extensions with an URL of that schema

{
    "fileMatch": "*.foo",
    "url": "fooSchema://schemas/schema"
  }

in the TextDocumentContentProvider, serve your JSON schema when requested and collect telemetry